# I am upgrading to Windows 10. I have Windows 8.1 Pro, which version of Windows 10 should I choose in the Downloader?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10

There is home, pro, home n, pro n. I have Windows 8.1 Pro, which version should I select?

Answer (score 3):

Pro. Pro N might work, but its a version without WMP and a few other things for places where they aren't allowed to bundle media player. [Paul Thurott](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/3887/windows-10-upgrade-matrix-which-version-you-get-for-free) has a pretty good writeup on that.

> Windows 8.1 will be upgraded to Windows 10 Home
>   Windows 8.1 with Bing will be upgraded to Windows 10 Home
>   Windows 8.1 Pro will be upgraded to Windows 10 Pro

Starter, home (and home premium) and bing editions (as exists for windows 7 and 8_  get upgraded to home. Pro and Ultimate get upgraded to windows 10 pro. Enterprise and RT don't get the free upgrade

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Lack of media player preinstalled in N. However its a europe/korea thing IIRC

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. I have chosen pro :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 8.1 Pro, during the [offered free upgrade you'll be upgraded to Windows 10 Pro](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq).

[image]

You don't have to choose anything.

Comment: My guess is this is for creating install media or downloading an ISO, there version matters.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the correct ESD is downloaded, so he still doesn't have to choose anything.